# Android Using Firebase to Find the Top 10 user

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I want to do the sorting and find out the top 5 biggest number base on the userCap for all the user. But my code didn't work. The type of variables in the database are String. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHgdk.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD9JU.jpg)

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
Query queryRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(uid).orderByChild("userCap").limitToLast(3);`

queryRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
@Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String userProfile = postSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
          //UserProfile userProfile = postSnapshot.getValue(UserProfile.class);
            Name.setText(dataSnapshot.child("userName").getValue(String.class));
            name=Name.getText().toString().trim();
            CapitalAmount.setText(dataSnapshot.child("userCap").getValue(String.class));
            cap=CapitalAmount.getText().toString().trim();

            Log.d("test"," values is " + Name  + " " + Cap);
            System.out.print("test value is :" + Name  + " " + Cap);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

Comment: Check that your uid is not null.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?